# Controller-View Interactions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm endeavoring to learn rails and am doing so by completing some super basic projects. The current thing I'm working on is a higher-lower game - the user guesses a number, and the server checks the guess against a randomly generated secret number, and responds if the guess is 'higher' or 'lower' than the actual number.

I've got most of the game complete, but I've realized I have no idea how to actually implement notifying the user if the guess was too high or too low. Other view changes in the game are handled by rendering a whole other page, but for this one I wish to display **new** text in the **current** page.

This question isn't really to solve my problem per se, I'm just trying to get pointed in the right general direction with controller-view interactions such as these.

Currently the only way I can think to do this is

**Logic in the View**

Make the data of whether the user guessed higher or lower available by using an instance variable, then use ruby in the html.erb view to determine what text to display based off this.

This seems ... dumb, and in violation of things I've learned about MVC in the past. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Would [flash messages](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) work here? You can refresh the same page, but see something else. If not, you can introduce a new variable in the controller `@answer` or something, and do an `if @answer ... show this message` in the view.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this in the "Rails" way would be to have a new path in your controller, for example `show_result`, and render a javascript view (`show_result.js.erb`). Then use a simple line of javascript to update the current DOM. Remember to set your form submission or your link to `:remote => true` and you're good to go.